# Colpitt oscillator transfer function

Tags: transistors, amplifier, oscillator, transfer-function, gain

Can you guys please help me find the symbolic transfer function Vout/Vin in this colpitt oscillator ?

[image]

Comment: When it settles-down to steady-state, it is running in a non-linear regime. You might limit your question to finding the **starting** transfer function, when oscillating signals are very small, but growing exponentially. At that early time, it runs nearly linearly.

Comment: Are you sure that you want the ratio Vout/Vin under closed-loop conditions? For what reason?

Comment: I would first study the amplifier built around the bipolar transistor (input at \$V_{in}\$ and output at its collector) and extract the transfer function. However, I am surprised by capacitor \$C_p\$ which complicates the analysis and introduces a RHP zero. Once this is done, I would determine the 4th-order transfer function linking the collector output to the input side \$V_{in}\$, considering \$C_{c1}\$ as a short circuit and neglecting the input impedance offered by the transistor compared to \$C_2\$'s impedance. It's a bit of work I reckon : )

Comment: Are you trying to find the oscillating frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to derive the transfer function of a Colpitts oscillator, you’d need to use the small signal model of the transistor since it’s operating as an amplifier. Then use circuit analysis to get Vout in terms of Vin, then divide Vout equation by Vin and simplify. To help consider the link below where they derive equations for a coltpitts oscillator using nodal analysis. Please note that you’ll have to include your components to the the model that are not included in the circuit in the link. Also you’ll have to somewhat diverge from their analysis at some point as they are finding as somewhat different transfer function.

Link: https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ese319/Lecture_Notes/Lec_19_Colpitts_Osc_09.pdf